# Capitalize letters in text file and save the changes - Java

Tags: java, capitalize

I have a text file with several names (I have listed few names as example):

```
eden ahbez, American musician
bill bissett, Canadian poet
asha bandele, American writer
danah boyd, American scholar
e e cummings, American poet
mc chris, American rapper
```

I want to capitalize each first letter of each word or name, including those after the comma. Whenever I try to do it, the output is showing only the first line and discarding the other lines and even it is not capitalizing the letters. How can I read from the same file, capitalize as mentioned, and save the changes in the same file? Because in my case, it is only reading the first line.

I use, for example this code to read the file:

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"));
    String phrase = "";
    String rline;

    while ((rline = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        phrase = rline;
        char[] line = phrase.toCharArray();
        for (r = 0; r < line.length; r++) {
            if (line[r] == ' ' && line[r] == ',' && line[r] != '.') {
                line[r + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(line[r + 1]);
            }
            output = Character.toString(line[r]);
            System.out.print(output);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    br1.close();
```

then this to save the changes:

```
PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter("names.txt");
pw1.println(output);
pw1.close();
```

Any suggestion?

[List of names from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_lower_case_names_and_pseudonyms)

Comment: Debug it and you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file

Comment: You override output every time in the loop `output = Character.toString(line[r]);`, so it contains only 1 line.

Comment: Problem has been solved with the instructions from the other answers. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The logical operator between `line[r] == ' '`  and `line[r] == ','` needs to be a logical OR `||` rather than a logical AND `&&` because a character can't BOTH.

Also this code will crash if there's a trailing space or a comma since the array won't contain an index of `r+1`. Lastly `&& line[r] != '.'` does nothing as the other two parts act like a whitelist. If the character is space or comma it will never also be period. Did you mean to make it `line[r] == '.'`? If so, it also needs a logical OR rather than logical AND.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you have two errors. First, your `if` is asking for something impossible (if `line[r]` is a space, and it's also a comma). It should instead be something like:

```
if (line[r] == ' ' && r + 1 < line.length) {
```

Second, you're always overwriting the contents of `output` with `=` instead of appending with `+=`, so that line should read:

```
output += Character.toString(line[r]);
```

If you run it like that, you'll notice it's missing something, first letter isn't getting capitalized, so you can put an extra conditional like this:

```
if (r == 0) {
    line[r] = Character.toUpperCase(line[r]);
}else if (line[r] == ' ' && r + 1 < line.length) {
    line[r + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(line[r + 1]);
}
```

Here you have a [working example](https://tio.run/##hVG9boMwEN7zFKcMKREtascqzRDlEdJOiOFiHHBqjGWbSGnFs9Mz0PKjRjkm/P2e7owXfCo1V@f087VpmERr4Z1b970AGuvQCQYHZ4TKQOcGLd@MEaEcGNjC8@Yfflk5XTlCl8sO1tVREtyzLqVIoUChgp6PJrNxsu6iW34b6A14yhVgfuRfj7AruBEMFRSVFUyg6t39sBxNnIAUyss6feTKPT3vjMFrsB64p9JA0JWnHd5aUSS5ylxOD2G4hqGJH3Fq6cSfI368OjYJ2fkwZI4bCv7Qmps9lQh6fJTvp@aSFvTOf/otPNC3WlGnEF6mvW4He@698JYzLzD56y8WTn2689zY4HC1jhcRKSNNNBd0HiPWEDHnSvV7j3pRN80P)

Comment: Thank you. Like you said, I was missing +=. I did all other corrections and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The logic to capitalize the initial letters is completely broken.
For example, the condition `line[r] == ' ' && line[r] == ',' && line[r] != '.'` will never be true.
Here's one way to fix that:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
        for (int r = 0; r < chars.length; r++) {
            if (r == 0 || chars[r - 1] == ' ') {
                chars[r] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[r]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new String(chars));
    }
}
```

I also changed the output mechanism to output the entire completed line instead of printing characters one by one.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned above

> You override output every time in the loop output =
>   Character.toString(line[r]);, so it contains only 1 line.

Also, your capitalization logic is too complex and broken as you can see from other answers.

So, I made it much easier this way:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"));
        String rline;
        String output = "";

        while ((rline = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lineArr = rline.split(" ");

            for (String word : lineArr) {
                word = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
                output += word + " ";
            }

            output += "\n";
        }

        System.out.print(output);

        br1.close();
    }
```

The Output:

```
Eden Ahbez, American Musician 
Bill Bissett, Canadian Poet 
Asha Bandele, American Writer 
Danah Boyd, American Scholar 
E E Cummings, American Poet 
Mc Chris, American Rapper
```

Answer (score 1):

WordUtils from org.apache.commons.lang implements many methods to manage texts. Here is an exapmple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "eden ahbez, American musician";
        System.out.println(WordUtils.capitalize(phrase));
}
```