# Text modification in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to modify text in a file but instead of modifying it, it is just adding a new line with the new information:

Here's my code

```
  String id= IDSearch.getText();
        String newname = NameText.getText();
        String newbarcode = BarcodeText.getText();
        String newsupplier= SupplierText.getText();
        String newamount1= AmountText.getText();


        ArrayList<Item> ItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (id.isEmpty() || newname.isEmpty() || newbarcode.isEmpty() || newsupplier.isEmpty() || newamount1.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, " Please Fill all fields");}
        else{
        try {
            File Items = new File ("Items.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(Items);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String data;
            Item tempItem;

            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        tempItem = new Item(data);
                        if (tempItem.getID().equals(IDSearch)) 
                        {
                            tempItem.setItemName(newname);
                            tempItem.setItemBarcode(newbarcode);
                            tempItem.setSupplierID(newsupplier);
                            tempItem.setAmount(newamount1);  

                        }
                        ItemsList.add(tempItem);
                    }
            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Items, true))) {

                    ItemsList.forEach((item) -> {
                        pw.println(newname + ";" + newbarcode+ ";" + newsupplier + ";" + newamount1);


                    });
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Student Updated Succesfully");

                } 
                }catch (IOException ex) {


        }
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to be able to update the tex file the way it was supposed to update. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you flushing and closing the writer

Comment: Where should I do that?

Comment: In a finally statement of the writing code. I never seen a try() like this in java, but this would be done when this statement is completed

Comment: Looks like it not working

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: @dirceusemighini when you use a try with resources block in java, any resource declared at the begining will close automatically at the end of the block. This works for anything that implements `autoCloseable`.

Comment: Nice @Touniouk I'd never seen this block, this is new for me.

Comment: @Neal Hampson, replace `pw.println([...]);` with `pw.write([...])`.

Comment: @Touniouk It's still adding it to the next line and not replacing it

Comment: @Touniouk Help! It's replaying all the text now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Replace Line In Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You have append set to `true`. Doing `new FileWriter(Items, false)` or just `(new FileWriter(Items)` should fix the issue.

Comment: Now it's either replacing all the text in the file or deleting all and leaving only one line. How do I fix that?

Comment: HELP ITS REPLACING ALL THE TEXT!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to replace only one line in the text file and not the whole text