# RandomAccessFile to modify a string at a specific line

Tags: java, file, parsing, randomaccessfile

**Introduction**

I challenged myself with this proyect.

I need to **modify data at a specific line** on a .txt **without doing** the next things:

- Loading everything on memory (Maps, Lists, Arrays...)
- Having to copy the file (such as -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file)) and thus eating space on the computer (imagine a huge file, massive!)
- No relational DBs and stuff alike

A simple .txt file  will have everything!

**Text file**

```
1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
2;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
3;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
4;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
5;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
6;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
```

follows this format which are Strings with ";" as separator.

**My code try which works for numbers from 0 to 9**

*(0 to 9 means this first number -> **1**;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;)*

```
public static void test(int lineNumber, String data)
    {
        String line;


          try{

              System.out.println("----DEBUG TEST----\n");

              RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("parking.txt", "rw");

              System.out.println("File pointer is: " + file.getFilePointer());

              System.out.println("Line size is: " + file.readLine().length());

              System.out.println("Read line is: " + (line = file.readLine()) + " with size: " + line.length());     

              file.seek(line.length());

              System.out.println("File pointer is: " + file.getFilePointer());

              file.writeChars("\n");
              file.writeBytes("7;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;");
              file.writeChars("\n");


              System.out.println("File pointer is: " + file.getFilePointer());

              System.out.println("Line size is: " + file.readLine().length());

              System.out.println("Read line is: " + (line = file.readLine()) + " with size: " + line.length());    


              file.seek(lineNumber);

              file.close();

          }catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}

          System.out.println("\n----DEBUG TEST----\n");        



    }
```

**Understanding the problem**

The string -> *1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;*

- Those last two '0' will be another date format as "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" and  a random (int) which add more length and it going to mess with the .txt

**Example: 
    1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;2019-06-01 10:11:16;100;**

- The first String is a number from 0 to the last entry number (it's a
  code)

I want to add them by replacing the String on it's position.

**Notes**

We will know at all times the size of the string we are going to modify (methods) and act accordingly.

**What do I expect from this**

Being able to modify the line from a file in Java. Which could be also a general method for this action.

Comment: Are all the lines the same length?

Comment: @guest Those I provide yes. But they will change overtime check out "Understanding the problem" if not. I will try to clarify it further.

Comment: It's always best to give explicit examples rather than a prose description of what might happen. For example, "I have `1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;` and want to replace it with `1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;123;`".

Comment: Next question: do you understand _why_ it's much better to replace while making a copy of the file? Or, are you OK if the file is destroyed by your replacement?

Comment: @guest There is no creation of a new file nor destruction by the replacement.

Comment: You cannot "change a line", you can only change specific bytes at specific locations in the file. Consequently, you can only change a line to a line of the same length. Otherwise, you will have to fully overwrite file's end. You can do that without loading it in memory in full, though.

Comment: @yeputons could you provide an example?

Comment: @WhiteGlove your code does exactly that: positions itself inside the file by reading some data (you cannot do anything else unless you know exact byte position, then you can use `setFilePointer`) and then calls `write*` to write new bytes

Comment: I know it works. But the question is... how can I still be able to do that if the size changes? (more bytes)

Comment: "There is no creation of a new file nor destruction by the replacement" - if you're changing the size of a single row then you need to move all of the bytes from that point onward -- either shrinking the file or expanding it. If that process fails for any reason -- such as someone tripping over a power cord -- you will have irrevocably corrupted your file.

Comment: That risk may be acceptable to you, but it's something that you have to consider _before_ writing any code. There are alternatives, such as append-only file formats, but whether or not they're appropriate will depend on your use case (which you don't describe). In general, however, creating a copy is the lowest-risk solution, and often the lowest cost (because disk is cheap).

Comment: @guest I went for a binary file to store data that I can control. Now I am working with 80 bytes of data and inside those 80 there are other divisions. I will post something once I finish it. But so far I am happy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *text file* to a storage media (i.e. HDD, RAM, Flash, etc). Computers always store everything in binary (i.e. bytes). *Text file* is a human concept.

Taking your example above:

```
1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
2;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
3;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
4;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
5;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
6;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
```

Here is how the first 2 lines looks to a computer (in HEX):

```
313B6173 64313332 343B3230 31392D30 352D3232 2031383A 32383A35 363B303B 303B0A
323B6173 64313332 343B3230 31392D30 352D3232 2031383A 32383A35 363B303B 303B0A
```

Note how the line is terminated (0A), which the end of line character for most *nix system. On Windows it will be 0D0A (or is it 0A0D?) and on a Mac it will be 0D.

Now to change a line, it must absolutely not be longer than the orignal one otherwise you will end up overwriting onto the start of the next line. Suppose you change the first line from

```
1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
```

to

```
1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;01;
```

you will end up with (first 2 lines):

```
313B6173 64313332 343B3230 31392D30 352D3232 2031383A 32383A35 363B303B 30313B
323B6173 64313332 343B3230 31392D30 352D3232 2031383A 32383A35 363B303B 303B0A
```

so your file will now be *read* as:

```
1;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;01;2;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
3;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
4;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
5;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
6;asd1324;2019-05-22 18:28:56;0;0;
```

You now have 5 lines instead of 6 since you have overwritten the line termination character of the original first line.

With all that said, modifying a text file without rewriting it can be a very tedious and hard task. It way faster and easier to rewrite the whole with your modifications. Otherwise, a military boot camp will feel like walk in the park in comparison.

Comment: Good answer. It helped me and I am doing progress but one more question. How I can do a professional (well made) binary (I decided I am going to work with binaries)

Comment: @WhiteGlove This is way too large topic for a simple discussion, IMHO. Google is your friend. Try searching for things like Java NIO for starter or maybe Java I/O.