# JAVA write on specific line using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a file called "contatti.txt" with some contact info, I need to write a string into a specific line of the txt file.

```
For example, I need to change the content of line 32 with "something..."
```

This is the code that let me write this file in append mode

```
File filee=new File("contatti.txt");

BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filee,true));
???
bw.close();
```

Comment: Create new temporary file, copy N-1 original lines to it, create modified version of N-th line and write it to temporary file, copy rest of the lines to temporary file. Replace original file with temporary one.

Comment: Is this SO question not the same as your question? [Java Replace Line In Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'll try it